# How can I check after a string in comparison not exists more characters?

Tags: bash

How can I check for example if `var` equal to string so that the last character is `s` ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by the title, but to provide an answer for your example: if you want to check if a string ends in `s`, use

```
if [[ $var = *s ]]; then
```

Comment: And if I want to do it with `grep` ?